# Is 'The reason is because ...' redundant?

Tags: idioms, dictionaries

> [[Source:]](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55524/50720) 
>   The phrase "the reason is" implies a causal relationship between two events or states.   For example, the reason that the wagon is red is that I painted it with red paint.
>   I could also say the wagon is red because I painted it.
>   CAUSE: I painted. EFFECT: <s>it</s> [the wagon] is red.
>
> So ... 3. “the reason is because,” ...
>   [=>] 4. The cause of there being a reason is that I painted it. ... 
>   [=] 5. “I painted the wagon and that is why it is red because I painted it.”

How does 3 => 4 => 5 ? Please show all steps and thought processes? I ask NOT about how, whether, or why this determiner phrase is claimed as redundant; I wish to justify its redundancy.

**Afterword:** Sorry for misleading, but I might've failed to ask my intended question. I was instead seeking an answer such as the following, from [here](https://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/tag/the-reason-is-because/), which user StoneyB kindly recommended:

> In a similar vein, some claim that because **because** usually means something like “for the reason that”, you’re really saying “The reason is for the reason that”
>   when you say[:] the reason is because.

Comment: Note to self: Adduce http://english.stackexchange.com/a/235133/50720

Answer (score 12):

The construction *The reason is because X* has been upsetting pedants for about four generations now. *Don't worry about it*: it is a fixed phrase and beyond grammatical niggling. Millions of people use it every day, in every register, and writers of the very first rank have used it for at least four hundred years.

If you want a reasoned discussion from a recognized expert you may consult the blog [*Motivated Grammar*](https://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/tag/the-reason-is-because/) written by Gabe Doyle of the Language and Cognition Lab at Stanford University:

> A mild amount of redundancy improves the likelihood of the message being transmitted correctly. The problem is when there’s too much redundancy, slowing down the rate of communication. (A common problem in children’s conversations, for instance, or a boring person’s stories.) Using *because* instead of *that* here doesn’t slow anything down, though — aside from the couple hundred milliseconds the additional syllable might cost the speaker — so I’m pretty unsympathetic to this complaint as well.

But I beg you, abandon the effort to understand the use of words by replacing them with their etymologies and dictionary definitions. That's not how any language works; it's a dead end for a learner.

Comment: +1 for *...upsetting pedants*; +5 for *Millions of people use it everyday* (didn't know that) and +10 for *That's not how any language works*. Dang it, can't vote more than once. ;)

Comment: This answer refers the reader to an outside resource for the answer. Far better to selectively quote from Doyle's article here: any one of the Woollcott, Frost or Wodehouse quotes would be great.  ["Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link which helped. Sorry for any confusion, but I might have neglected (abstractedly) to ask the intended question. Is my question clearer now?

Comment: I know that I just edited my OP substantially, but please clarify if your answer explains 'How does 3 => 4 => 5 ?' This I did write in the original OP.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit If you read Doyle's post you will find "Simple-minded definition replacement isn’t a good argument", with a reductio ad absurdum showing that this sort of analysis can be applied to any sort of utterance. He goes on to say "(Furthermore, if you see a word being consistently used in a way that doesn’t fit its standard meaning, then that meaning is inappropriate for that use of the word.)"

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** analyze a sentence in a natural language — any natural language — by syntactic substitution and rearrangement, the way you are trying to do. Natural languages do not work that way.  Your "3 => 4 => 5" is [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

You are also proceeding from an incorrect assumption: the phrase "The reason is because" is *not* redundant.  It can be shortened to "The reason is" *without changing the meaning*, but that doesn't mean the word "because" is redundant!  It is just playing a non-semantic role.

So it's not redundant, so what is it doing?  First, think about spoken language.  All spoken languages have [filler words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29), which have no semantics but convey "I'm not done talking, I need a little more time to think of how to say the next thing."  There are *generic* filler words, such as "uh" and "um", that can be used anywhere, but native speakers will often use words that fit grammatically and don't add any semantics, instead.  If someone said "the reason is because X" out loud, the *because* would be a filler word in that sense.  Again, it's not redundant, it's said for its effect on the *conversation* rather than on the *communication*.

Now, in written language there is no need for filler, but there *is* a notion of rhythm and flow, and English permits a fair amount of flex in sentence structure for the sake of rhythm and flow.  Here are two examples (from [the document linked in StoneyB's answer](https://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/tag/the-reason-is-because/)) where *because* improves the flow of the sentence:

> “If the fellow who wrote it seems to know more of my goings and comings than he could without complicity of mine, **the reason is because** he is a lovely old boy and quite took possession of me while I was in Boston”
>     [1915, Robert Frost]
>
> “… one of **the reasons** why I am not particularly well read today **is because** I have spent so large a part of the last twenty years rereading Dickens and Jane Austen.”
>   [1932, Alexander Woollcott]

Sentence flow is a highly subjective thing which you have to learn by osmosis.  Don't worry about it until you are able to read fiction in English for pleasure without a dictionary.  Then read a lot of fiction in many different styles, and your ear for it will begin to develop.

Comment: I know that I just edited my OP substantially, but please clarify if your answer explains 'How does 3 => 4 => 5 ?' This I did write in the original OP.

Comment: I have revised my answer and I hope it makes my point clearer, but I cannot *explain* "How does 3 => 4 => 5", I can only *refute* it.  It's [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

Comment: Reading over your second example, I wonder if the "because" serves some small purpose in reminding the listener of the beginning of the sentence. _The reason I haven't written my own answer to this question which I found interesting for several different reasons that I'm not going to even attempt to explain in such a small comment box is because I can't improve upon the existing answers._ I also think "because" is easier to follow along with when listening to someone speak. "The reason for it is (that) that term is wrong."  versus "The reason for it is because that term is wrong."

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, I think you're right.  That is often (one of) the functions of "redundancies" in spoken language.  The longer the gap between "the reason" and "is", the more useful the extra word becomes.

Comment: @zwol I can happily change which answer to accept, but why can't one explain how 3 can be interpreted to mean 4, then the same for 4 to 5? I meant => as 'can be interpreted to mean' ?

Comment: You have taken a sentence, shuffled its words around and syntactically substituted dictionary definitions for some of the words, assumed that the result is a well-formed sentence meaning the same thing as the original, and asked for a rationale. You can't do this. It is an invalid procedure and an invalid question. Any answer I could make up would only serve to confuse you further.

Comment: In your comment of 2014/Mar/24, 1912 GMT, does the first word `you` refer to me? I did NOT write 3, 4, and 5; I only cited the author who did? So are you saying that his/her sentences are unsound?

Comment: I apologize; I did not understand that to be a quotation.  Indeed, that person's sentences and logic are unsound. But your own answer to that question commits the same error. You can't "substitute the definition".  You just can't. (Of all the answers to that question, only https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34876/1475 is in any way accurate.  I am tempted to copy and paste this answer over there.)

Answer (score -3):

It's not a question of redundancy; it's a question of correctness.

Consider this example:

> Patient: I missed my appointment!
>   Doctor: What was the reason?

Some potential responses are:

> 1. The reason *was the fact that* I overslept.
> 2. The reason *came about* because I overslept.
> 3. The reason *was* because I overslept.

Now consider the meaning of each:

1. Sentence 1 implies the patient was either asleep at the time of his appointment, or it was otherwise impossible for him to make it in time (e.g. due to transportation delay)
2. Sentence 2 implies the reason was something else entirely, but the *original cause* was the fact that he overslept. For example, he might have overslept, his house might have caught fire when he was asleep, and he might have had to deal with that instead of coming to his appointment.
3. Sentence 3 actually means the same thing as **sentence 2**, but it's not obvious because the verb here is **"was"**, and "was" is a passive verb -- it isn't in a position to receive the emphasis in this sentence. If you change "is" to "exists", you will see that the the meaning matches that of sentence 2.

Comment: I know that I just edited my OP substantially, but please clarify if your answer explains 'How does 3 => 4 => 5 ?' This I did write in the original OP.

Comment: "The reason was because I overslept. " doesn't have a different meaning than "The reason was that I overslept. " as I've heard it used in this context . Do you have any examples that support a difference in meaning ? It could be a difference in dialect I suppose.

Comment: @ColleenV: the whole point is that that's the intended meaning, not the actual meaning. The actual meaning is the same as what you get when you replace "is" with "exists".

Comment: I am trying to say that the way that the folks I've been in contact with use it there's no difference, actual or intended. I'm interested in understanding why you see a difference when my experience is that there is none (at least in my flavor of AmE). Changing the verb changes the meaning; is is not exists.

Comment: @ColleenV: well, do you see the difference when we replace the verb to be with existance? The two words are synonyms.

Comment: She existed. She was. She was an Engineer. ✳She existed an Engineer✳. "To be" is only a synonym for "exist" in certain contexts. "The reason is X" is not the same as "The reason exists X".

Comment: @ColleenV: Are you just trying to argue for the sake of arguing or is it really that hard to understand? I said it's a **synonym**, I didn't say it's a blind drop-in replacement. The meaning is the same, but you still need to make it grammatically correct. In this case, it might be "She existed *as an* engineer." Any dictionary or thesaurus you look up "to be" in will list "exist" as the primary meaning. Did you try it? [Here, I'll link you.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/be) Now go find me a dictionary that lists *your* definition as the meaning.

Comment: [Be](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/be#be_1 "intransitive verb, def. 2, Collins"): `as a copula, be links its subject to a predicate nominative, adjective, or pronoun so as to express attribution or identity, and by extension, value, cause, signification, etc.; it is sometimes equivalent to the mathematical sign (=)   ⇒ Mrs. Siddons was an actress`. _"She was an Engineer"_ is not the same as _"She existed as an Engineer"_. I'm not sure how you would put "exists" into "The reason was X." without including "to be", like: "The reason existed and it was X"

Comment: @ColleenV: You're missing the entire point. The point isn't that the word "exist" is a 100% accurate substitute (it isn't, but it's the closest one I can find); the same problem would happen *no matter what* word you substitute for "to be" -- whether it's "exist", "occur", "happen", whatever word pleases you. *Any* word you put in there makes the sentence have a different meaning than what is intended. The particular verb "to be" doesn't somehow change the grammar; the grammar is the same.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you think there's a difference in meaning, and you said essentially,  put exists in there and it's obvious. I'm not getting it though. I'm sincerely trying to understand your point, and I'm sure if we were talking instead of writing I would have gotten it by now. Maybe if you type slower and louder ;)